# cxf 2.7.7 under Windows can't process dateTime Elements

Tags: java, soap, cxf

In my wsdl I am defining birthDate element like so:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="birthDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

What happens when this element in the soap envelope exists but is empty i.e.

```
<birthDate></birthDate>
```

I get the following exception

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error:
```

and further down in the stack

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; ]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:842)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:870)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:868)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; 
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:691)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:687)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.FilterTransducer.parse(FilterTransducer.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:514)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:338)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:216)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:185)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ]
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseAndSetYear(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2887)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2773)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(DatatypeFactoryImpl.java:536)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:583)
    ... 49 more
```

However whenever element is not present or set to something i.e.

```
<birthDate>1907-07-16T19:20:30</birthDate>
```

everything works fine.

What adds to the confusion is the fact that this issue appears only when working under Windows. There are no issues under Linux.

What could cause this weirdness? How can I work around it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this JIRA on the Apache site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2964), which lists a very similar exception to yours:

> `<ns2:SUBMITDATE></ns2:SUBMITDATE>` does not make it null. That make it an empty string which is invalid for a date and JAXB is properly throwing an IllegalArgumentException in this case. If you want it null, it should be:
>   `<ns12:SUBMITDATE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>`
>   Thus, the incoming XML is invalid per schema and CXF/JAXB is working as designed.

Not sure why it would work on Linux but not on Windows.